# Python Pandas how to check if a dataframe is saved correctly without loss of information?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have  data frame with datetime as index and it's shape is `(1.7 million rows, 50 columns)` and I am saving it as a `.csv` file. Now I want to make sure the data frame is saved correctly and there is no loss of information or missed information.

My check is:

```
# save original dataframe
origdf.to_csv('/blawblaw.csv')

# again import the saved dataframe, this for cross check
imdf = pd.read_csv('/blawblaw.csv')

# Check1 to see both dataframes are same
origdf.shape
Out[79]: (1776798, 50)
imdf.shape
Out[79]: (1776798, 51)

#check2 
origdf['one_binarycolumn'].value_counts()
Out[]: 
True     1643769
False     133029
Name: one_binarycolumn, dtype: int64

indf['one_binarycolumn'].value_counts()
Out[]: 
True     1643769
False     133029
Name: one_binarycolumn, dtype: int64
```

My question is, is there a better way than what I did here?

Comment: I think validating shape is more than enough.
If you want to verify equality of values you may try `DataFrame.equals`. But in your case you need to save without index.

Answer (score -1):

try to save

```
pd.to_csv('/blawblaw.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: How does that check if it is saved correctly?